# Eclipse does not catch breakpoints in servlets - weblogic

Tags: eclipse, debugging, weblogic, breakpoints, remote-debugging

I'm using remote debbuging on Weblogic and for some reason, eclipse does not stop at breakpoints in my servlets anymore, as if the sources and the version deployed are de-synced. 
All the other breakpoints works fine. Even those in my  jsp. 
All the sources are referenced in the debug configuration.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I assume you've tried the standard refresh, clean all projects, build all? Make sure your classpath doesn't have any issues as well.

Comment: Yes, I have tried all the yadayada. Sometimes in other classes, it would also miss a breakpoint and I have to break somewhere before and walk until I get to the one uncaught then it works fine afterwards.